# IT Hit WebDAV - Document corrupting when you delete all the content

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdav, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

When I edit a document using the WebDAV server from IT Hit, I can add content to a Word Document. However if I select it all and delete it all or reduce it down to one word, it then opens as corrupted. In the 2013 version of Word I am able to repair the document. I have attached some screenshot of I came to the error, a before and after repair of the file and how the document looks in beyond compare.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

**The Error**
[image: Error]

**Beyond Compare**
[image: Beyond compare]

**Settings Difference**
[image: Settings]

**Core Difference**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified that current Server Engine for .Net v3.9.2075.0 and Ajax File Browser v2.6.2.2105 works with no problem. I double checked server with both SQL beck-end and with file system back-end. I tested both ASP.NET server running in IIS Express and in HttpListener.

Here is what you can try that may give you an idea of waht is wrong:

- Execute 'net use * /DELETE'. This will unmount all network shares
  including WebDAV. This will simulate 'clean' environment.
- Examine the WebDAVLog.txt. By default it is located in /App_Data/WebDAV/Logs/. Are there any exceptions in it?
- Capture requests using free Fiddler tool or any other debugging
  proxy. Are there any failed requests?

Comment: After checking the logs I notice the size coming out of WebDAV was different from what I was saving. After investigation the problem was down to the way we were saving data to Azure Table storage. Many thanks.